# How to return an error from a class

Tags: c#, class, imagemagick

I am new to c# and I don't know if I am doing this right. My problem is that I need to return the error from a class(.dll) but I don't know how.It only returns true or false. This is the code of my class:

```
namespace DigitalAssetConverter
{
    public class ConvertImage
    {
        public Boolean ImagePath(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
                settings.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.RGB;

                using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(filePath))
                {
                    image.Read(filePath, settings);
                    image.Resize(500, 500);
                    image.Write(Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".jpg"));
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
  private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConvertImage ci = new ConvertImage();
        if (ci.ImagePath(@"C:\tryConvert\LP_10078.eps"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Success!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omit the `try/catch` block and make the return type void:

```
public void ImagePath(string filePath)
{
    MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
    settings.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.RGB;

    using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(filePath))
    {
        image.Read(filePath, settings);
        image.Resize(500, 500);
        image.Write(Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".jpg"));
    }
}
```

The exception (if any) will bubble up on its own, and you can place a `try/catch` block in the `btnConvert_Click` event to handle it instead:

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConvertImage ci = new ConvertImage();

    try
    {
        ci.ImagePath(@"C:\tryConvert\LP_10078.eps")
        MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```